# How to display the values in a pie chart - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, pie-chart

So I have recently starting using apps script to create a dashboard that creates charts. However for the life of me, I can't get the pie slice text to show up. I've tried a lot of ways based on solutions I found online, but I think I now need someone's help to know if I'm doing something wrong in my code.

Here is the sheet with some dummy data.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tPc0KU2uYuN4rO32tW-s6lql_IW57kbDUdSR8ZSkVXY/edit?usp=sharing

I had a lot of formatting for the texts and the labels etc, however I removed it all just to see if that was causing an issue. The PieSliceText, or data label, still won't show. Its super frustrating as I've been at it for a couple of days now. Hoping that someone will respond on the query!:)

And here is the code that I'm using:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var chartDataRange = sheet.getRange('G2:H5');   
  var pieChartTitle = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('I71').getValue();
  var pieChartBuilder = sheet.newChart()
     .addRange(chartDataRange)
     .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.PIE)
     .setOption('Slices',{0:{pieSliceText:'value'},1:{pieSliceText:'value'},2:{pieSliceText:'value'}})
     .setPosition(2,1,0,0)
     .setOption('title', pieChartTitle)
     .setOption('width',500).setOption('height',300)
     .setOption('pieHole',0.5)
     .build();
  
    sheet.insertChart(pieChartBuilder);
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking to display the values of the slices, try this:

```
.setOption('pieSliceText', 'value')
```

**Code snippet:**

Value `350` does not appear because it is a very small slice compared to the other two.

```
function createPieChart() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var chartDataRange = sheet.getRange('G2:H5');   
  var pieChartTitle = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('I71').getValue();
  var pieChartBuilder = sheet.newChart()
     .addRange(chartDataRange)
     .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.PIE)
     .setOption('pieSliceText', 'value')
     .setPosition(2,1,0,0)
     .setOption('title', pieChartTitle)
     .setOption('width',500).setOption('height',300)
     .setOption('pieHole',0.5)
     .build();
    sheet.insertChart(pieChartBuilder);
 }
```

[image: label]

---

**References:**

[Visualization: Pie Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart)

Comment: Is there a reason why the quotes need to be added there instead of the way I was doing it?

Comment: @JayyJangam quotes in my code are used because you are referring to a parameter option `'pieSliceText'`. If you used just `pieSliceText` it would drop an error since there ino variable with the name `pieSliceText`. In your case, you define a json object which keys don't require quotes and hence it does not drop an error. But the way to define the values like that in a pie chart is not correct.

Comment: Hmmm, I see okay, I was defining it the same way that i did for other chart types, but I guess that its not the correct way for this type. Thank you so much for your quick answer and I've marked it as answered!:)